# Storing world info in RPG game

Tags: global-variables, state, flags

I am working on an RPG game and I am wondering at the ways to store game world state information, like "did talk to character X" flags, flags on finished quests, etc. A typical RPG could have hundreds of such - let's say - global variables to hold all that state info, but are variables the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has some good info.

http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-does-fallout-nv-lag-explain-skyrim-issues

> "It's an engine-level issue with how the save game data is stored off as bit flag differences compared to the placed instances in the main .esm + DLC .esms," Sawyer explained, referencing the database files used by the Fallout 3/New Vegas engine, which remain in place in Skyrim.
>
> "As the game modifies any placed instance of an object, those changes
>   are stored off into what is essentially another .esm. When you load
>   the save game, you're loading all of those differences into resident
>   memory."